# DIV object and an Overlay object, prototypal inheritance issue with html elements?

Tags: javascript, object, element, prototype

I have a very unique problem, and I am not sure as to how I should tackle it, whether there is a best way to tackle it, and/or if this is a design pattern flaw.

The reason for asking is that I believe I should not have to re-write functions for the same functionality. Take below the example code;

```
 function Div(config) {

     var config = config || {};
     this.element = document.createElement("div");
     this.setSize(config.width || 0, config.height || 0);
 };

 Div.prototype.setSize = function(width, height) {

     this.setWidth(width);
     this.setHeight(height);
 };

 Div.prototype.setWidth = function(width) {

     this.element.style.width = width + "px";
 };

 Div.prototype.setHeight = function(height) {

     this.element.style.height = height + "px";
 };

 Div.prototype.appendTo = function(element) {

     element.appendChild(this.element);
 };
```

You can see that the above code allows me to create `div` tags. I can easily create html divs, set their size and append them to other elements.

I also have an `Overlay` object which needs to inherit `Div`. At first I decided to set `Div` as `Overlay`'s prototype.

```
 function Overlay(config) {

      var config = config || {};
      this.setSize(config.width, config.height);
 };

 Overlay.prototype = new Div();
```

This worked fine, but the problem arises because `Overlay` is essentially a `Div` with some added functionality. As the `Overlay` object has `Div` as its prototype it only points to one div element, whereas each instance of `Overlay` should have its own div element.

I then decided to make `Div` a property of `Overlay`;

```
 function Overlay(config) {

     var config = config || {};
     this.div = new Div(config);
 };
```

This also works fine, but now when creating instances of `Overlay` I would have to use it like so;

```
 var overlay = new Overlay();
 overlay.div.setSize(100, 100);
```

Rather than;

```
 var overlay = new Overlay();
 overlay.setSize(100, 100);
```

To tackle this I created new prototypal functions on `Overlay` to simplify using it, `Overlay` as it stands now looks like this;

```
 function Overlay(config) {

     var config = config || {};
     this.div = new Div(config);
 };

 Overlay.prototype.setSize = function(width, height) {

     this.div.setWidth(width);
     this.div.setHeight(height);
 };

 Overlay.prototype.setWidth = function(width) {

     this.div.setWidth(width);
 };

 Overlay.prototype.setHeight = function(height) {

     this.div.setHeight(height);
 };

 Overlay.prototype.appendTo = function(element) {

     this.div.appendTo(element);
 };
```

Creating `Overlay` like this is exactly how I want the functionality for `Overlay` to be, but it seems very wrong to me that this is how it should be done as I am literally writing functions for the sake of ease of use, and as `Div` grows in size maintainability would become a real pain.

Whereas setting `Div` as `Overlay`'s prototype seems the correct way to do things, but in my case it obviously isn't as then all instances of `Overlay` are tied to the same div element.

How can I create both a `Div` object, and an `Overlay` object, where `Overlay` will have its own instance of `Div` but will also inherit all of `Div`'s functionality to its prototype? Is there a pattern that I should be using to tackle this problem I am facing?

I am literally stuck as to where to go from here, but I think I am pretty sure that the way I am doing it now is not the correct way!

Thanks for taking the time to read my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make your code work and allow you to remove all those added functions, add the following into your `Overlay` constructor:

```
Div.call(this);
```

And add this line after declaring the `Overlay` constructor:

```
Overlay.prototype = Object.create(Div.prototype);
```

---

**EXPLANATION:**
Here is a more verbose breakdown of what we're doing. First, define the `Div` constructor and give its prototype some functionality:

```
function Div() {
    this.propA = true;
}
Div.prototype.sayMyProp = function(){
   alert(this.propA);   
};
```

Define the `Overlay` constructor:

```
function Overlay() {
    Div.call(this);  // This gives any Overlay object the properties of Div
    // Define some properties specific to Overlay
    this.propB = true;
}
```

Create a new prototype for `Overlay` that inherits from `Div`'s prototype:

```
Overlay.prototype = Object.create(Div.prototype);
```

Note that this does *not* copy the properties of `Div.prototype` onto `Overlay.prototype`, it just creates an `Overlay.prototype` object which has a "parent" reference to `Div.prototype`. `Overlay.prototype` has no properties of its own (though it would have had a `constructor` property if we had not overwritten it).  Next, test our structure by creating two instances of `Overlay`:

```
var o1 = new Overlay();
var o2 = new Overlay();

o1.propA = false;  // Does not change o2.propA because it is an "own"
                   // property of Overlay instances
```

They have access to the functions on Div's prototype:

```
o1.sayMyProp();    // FALSE
o2.sayMyProp();    // TRUE, so they are not sharing the same propA
```

**FIDDLE:**
Here is a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sh0ber/FumdC/)

Comment: Thank you this is very helpful! I knew I was doing something wrong somewhere.